# Is == operator faster than equals()?

Tags: java, string

I'm learning String intern() method and know that intern() help me can compare String object using "==" operator over equals() method and some document cite that more quickly. Isn't it?

> https://dzone.com/articles/string-interning-what-why-and

Comment: Of course it is. It just compares memory addresses. The `==` and `equals(...)` have different semantics. Because they have different semantics, I would highly discourage use interchangably use them. I would rather advice to use `equals(...)` when one wants to check for equality and only use `==` when semantics demand that the exact same object (at the exact same memory address) is required.

Comment: @Turing85: Why compare memory addresses faster? Sorry if my question seem a bit stupid.

Comment: A memory address is just a 32-bit or 64-bit integer (depending on the CPU architecture). Comparision can be done with a single CPU instruction in a single CPU cycle.

Comment: @Turing85: Is 1/processor speed (E.g: 2.5GHz), right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** Don't use `==` to compare strings.

Specifically with regard to strings, yes, `==` is **slightly** faster than `equals`, because the first thing the `String.equals` method does is...a `==` comparison to see if the string is being compared to itself. If it is, `equals()` is slower by the cost of a method call. If it isn't, `equals` is slower by that cost plus the cost of comparing the characters in the strings.

**But** remember that before you can use `==` to compare strings (which is a Bad Idea™), you have to know for sure that **both** strings are interned. The combination of `intern()` and `==` is **not** faster than `equals()`. `intern()` is a relatively expensive operation, as it involves looking for an equivalent string already in the intern pool, which may involve lots and lots of `equals()` calls (or their equivalent).

There may be some ***extremely rare*** edge cases where it's reasonable to incur that `intern()` cost and then use `==` on strings you know are interned. For instance, if you have a large static set of strings that you compare to one another **really** frequently. But that's an extremely unusual edge situation.

Bottom line: Don't compare strings with `==`. Don't intern strings unnecessarily.

Comment: Can you specify one case that using `intern()` and `==` operator over `equals()` method when to compare two String. @T.J Crowder

Comment: @logbasex - I mention one in the second to last paragraph of the answer (I added it later, you may not have seen it).